# Unable to find the packagemaker command line tool in Mac 10.8

Tags: macos, command-line, osx-mountain-lion, packagemaker

I am using Mac 10.8 and Xcode 4.4.1 . I have installed command line tools for Xcode 4.4.1 and Auxilium tools for xcode 4.4.1 (Package Maker ). I have put the PackageMaker.app into applications folder. I am looking for command line tool for Package Maker. I have searched through web and found some commands.

```
/Developer/usr/bin/packagemaker --verbose --doc [project].pmdoc --out [project].pkg mkdir -p dmg
```

But I am unable to find the `“/Developer/usr/bin/packagemaker”` location in my machine. Is there anything I missed to configure for this? I am installing Mac Port also. Please update me is there any option from Mac Port also. Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `PackageMaker` command line tool is inside the app. Right click PackageMaker.app and choose `Show Package Contents`.

The full path to PackageMaker if you installed PackageMaker.app to Applications would be:

```
/Applications/PackageMaker.app/Contents/MacOS/PackageMaker
```

Comment: upper/lowercase shouldn't matter unless you installed MacOS with case sensitive file system

Answer (score 6):

While the man pages haven't been updated (please file a radar on that) the **new** utilities are /usr/bin/pkgbuild and /usr/sbin/pkgutil.

Comment: theoretically these only get installed when the developer also installs the "Command Line Tools for Xcode" package (either the standalone download or from within Xcode itself).